# How to properly define return type from internal function?

Tags: react-redux, flowtype

I have an HOC defined as follows:

```
export default withLocale = (includeDispatch: boolean = false) => {
  const mapStateToProps = (state: Object) => ({
    locale: R.prop('locale', state)
  })
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    changeLocale: (locale: LocalesType) => dispatch(changeLocale(locale))
  })
  return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    includeDispatch ? mapDispatchToProps : undefined
  ) 
}
```

What I am struggling with is how to define the Flow return Type of this function. `connect` has several definitions in TS, but none defined in Flow. Is there a way to infer the return type from connect? Also, how does one even go about defining a return type using this function definition syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The flow-typed repository has a definition for react-redux, which you can find [here](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm/react-redux_v5.x.x/flow_v0.30.x-).

I have personally found that is missing some functionality, so I have a modified version [here](https://gist.github.com/rsolomon/397292b51fff7a66f8ff23a4afa91a60) that you're free to use. However, it doesn't work well with stateless functional components, which is why I haven't issued a pull request for it yet.